# Could someone explain what these .htaccess rules and ".well-known" conditions are for?

Tags: htaccess, apache, mod-rewrite

I am confused about both the purpose of `.well-known` exceptions and so many conditions. Is this just something temporarily put in place by the host or is it best practice to keep it in place? Why are there two sets of conditions and rules. Can they be combined into one set?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/(?:\Ballot169)?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} =POST
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*(opera|mozilla|firefox|msie|safari).*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.+/trackback/?\ HTTP/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/(?:\ Ballot169)?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule .? - [F,NS,L]
```

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: Is there a particular part that is confusing to you?   Are you asking about what the `.well-known` exceptions are for, or are you asking what the purpose of the rule is?

Comment: I am confused about both the purpose of .well-known exceptions and so many conditions. Is this just something temporary put in place by the host or is it best practice to keep it in place? Why are there two sets of conditions and rules. Can they be combined into one set? I really do not know much about .htaccess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why are there two sets of conditions and rules. Can they be combined into one set?

These are two rules that serve two different purposes - they cannot be combined. Taking out the (unnecessary) ".well-known" conditions, we have:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} =POST
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*(opera|mozilla|firefox|msie|safari).*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.+/trackback/?\ HTTP/ [NC]
RewriteRule .? - [F,NS,L]
```

The first is an HTTP to HTTPS redirect. (Which should really be a 301 permanent redirect, not a 302 temporary redirect as it is currently written.)

The second rule would seem to block [Trackbacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trackback). This is a "feature" that allows websites/blogs (particularly WordPress) to acknowledge *linkbacks* to articles and is often shown as a *comment*. However, this can be abused by spammers, hence the desire to block them.

> I am confused about both the purpose of `.well-known` exceptions and so many conditions. Is this just something temporary put in place by the host or is it best practice to keep it in place?

These *conditions* play no part in the rules themselves, they are simply creating exceptions so the rules don't run when these requests are made. This occurs when your host auto-renews security certificates.

They are only needed temporarily (if at all). However, they are likely to be required again in a few (3?) months time when the certificates are next renewed.

However, as noted by @Stephen in comments, for these particular rules, the conditions are most probably superfluous anyway. However, cPanel does not discriminate, it blindly adds these conditions before *every* `RewriteRule` directive. If you manually remove them then cPanel is likely to add them back when it comes to cert renewal (as mentioned).

See also my answers on the following ServerFault questions for more information regarding these conditions:

- [Apache htaccess multiple rewrite conditions for multiple rules](https://serverfault.com/questions/884915/apache-htaccess-multiple-rewrite-conditions-for-multiple-rules)
- [Explanation of new line in htaccess file: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/.well-known/pki-validation/(?:\ Ballot169)?](https://serverfault.com/questions/963847/explanation-of-new-line-in-htaccess-file-rewritecond-request-uri-well-k)

Comment: The `.well-known` exceptions shouldn't ever be needed on the last rule. If the URL has "trackback" in it, it is unlikely to ever match a `./well-known/` URL.

Comment: I'm also not sure why you would need an exception for `.well-known/acme-challenge` for the HTTPS redirect. LetsEncrypt follows redirects when validating site ownership and will issue certificates even if the site redirects somewhere else.  It just needs to have the correct challenge response at the end of the redirect.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller True. Unfortunately cPanel appears to blindly add these conditions before _every_ `RewriteRule` regardless. If you remove them then they are likely to reappear. The 3rd condition that includes "Ballot169" is a bit of a strange one (mentioned in the linked question above) as it basically renders the 4th condition superfluous!?

Comment: Thank you MrWhite for editing my question and illustrating a simplified version of the code. Thank you MrWhite and Stephen Ostermiller for discussing the whys and wherefores. I no longer have WordPress installed on that domain so it would seem that blocking Trackbacks is redundant. The HTTP to HTTPS redirect I believe was put in place to give the impression to visitors that the site is secure when in fact I have no certificate so I believe I should remove that as well. I think my host provides a free certificate but in order to implement it I need to have a dedicated IP, which I do not.

Comment: "The HTTP to HTTPS redirect I believe was put in place to give the impression to visitors that the site is secure when in fact **I have no certificate**" - You can't redirect to HTTPS unless you have a valid certificate. (?) Your users would either get a browser warning telling them that the cert is invalid (at best) or the browser will simply fail to connect (if you have no cert at all).

Comment: However, you don't necessarily need a "dedicated IP" to have a cert these days. If your host is offering a "free" cert then it's probably using [SNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) - supported by all modern browsers. By the abundance of _conditions_ in your `.htaccess` file, it looks like the host may have already enabled this for you?

Comment: The redirect to https seems to work without errors so most likely my host is enabling this for all the domains on my shared hosting account.

Comment: I am gradually converting my WordPress websites to Bootstrap 4, and from what you are saying it seems that I  can get rid of the Trackbacks RewriteRule all together.